# How to reduce 10 minutes from current timestamp in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using DB2 database and able to fetch data using below SQL. Here, I am looking for data
of last 10 minutes. Here `CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 10 MINUTE` is nothing but subtracting 10 minutes from current timestamp.

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE param1 = '1234' AND param2 = '1' AND param3 = '0' AND DATE_TS > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 10 MINUTE;
```

I am facing issue while using it with Hibernate Query Language. In Hibernate, I am able to perform the same using Native Query. But, I have to do it with HQL. How can I do it? How to reduce 10 minutes from current timestamp at SQL level.

Note: I tried in Java using reducing 10 minutes from system timestamp. But I see there TIMEZONE difference of 12Hrs. So not able to get results of last 10 minutes.

Comment: You can use `java.time` here, but you have to take care of the time zone, especially when a value is coming from a different system like your database. Might happen that no information about the time zone is actually passed within the value, you would have to know which zone the database is storing the values in. In Java, you can use a `ZonedDateTime` for operations including time zones (`java.time.ZoneId`).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
LocalDateTime checkForDate = LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(10);
createQuery("SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE param1 = '1234' AND param2 = '1' AND param3 = '0' AND DATE_TS >:checkForDate").setParameter("checkForDate", java.sql.timestamp.valueOf(checkForDate));
```

Comment: I have tried this however I see the difference in Time zone. E.g. Java timeStamp=2022-01-07 14:45:36.964 & SQL  timeStamp=2022-01-07-03.16.18.671103

Comment: I am able to do it though Native SQL query, so I am good. Thanks!